# What to expect when using plus operator for different types in SQL?

Tags: sql, operators, standards

I was wondering if there is a defined SQL standard response when using the + operator among different data types.

i.e. `SELECT (int_col + char_col + float_col) AS mixed_value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plus sign operator has been defined since ANSI SQL-86, the first SQL standard.  It defines, among other things, addition between numbers, intervals, and dates and intervals.  There is no standard method of handling a plus sign operator with character data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are including a char column, you will get a conversion error when you try to run the query if the char field does not have something that can be converted to a number.  The system will add the numbers together if they are all numbers.  It will convert the int to a float.  Here is some test data:

```
/* Appending all three types together */
SELECT (int_field + char_field + float_field) AS NewField
FROM DataTypes
/* Results: Success only when the char can be converted to a number
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'test      ' to data type int.
*/

/* Appending only numeric types (float and int) */
SELECT (int_field + float_field) AS NewField
FROM DataTypes
/* Results: Success */

/* Appending char and int types */
SELECT (char_field + int_field) AS NewField
FROM DataTypes
/* Results: Succes only when the char can be converted to a number
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'test      ' to data type int. */


/* Appending char and nvarchar types */
SELECT (char_field + nvarchar_field) AS NewField
FROM DataTypes
/* Results: Success */
```

Notice in the last couple results that if there are only text fields, they will append to each other.  However, if even one numeric field is present, the system tries to convert them all to numeric, regardless of order.  Whenever the plus operator is used, if even one field is numeric the system assumes the operation is one of addition not appending.

This was tested on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: SQL Server will not do that - it requires you to use CAST or CONVERT. MySQL and Oracle are more forgiving with implicit conversion, but Oracle uses the double pipe ("||") to concatenate strings - not the "+".  The double pipe is also now the ANSI standard for concatenating strings.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - SQL server (at least 2008) does allow implicit conversions, even of char fields if they contain only numbers, as my examples show.  The first query did work if the char field contained "10        " but it didn't work if I put "ten       " in it.

Comment: The first data type determines what the subsequent values will be implicitly converted to, iirc.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - Actually, I didn't find that to be true.  I updated my example to include one where the char field was first.  I would have thought that the order was important, but it isn't.  If a numeric field is involved, the system tries to convert the entire thing to numeric.